# pass return argument value one function to another flask

Tags: python, flask

I would like to return a value from one function to another function and use it to filter my excel.
Below is what am trying to do:

```
@app.route('/bzrules')
def show_tables():
    rules = pd.read_excel('static/dummy_data.xlsx')
    # User will select value in drop down in view.html. I want the user selection to be passsed to my second function below to filter my excel sheet
    subarealist = rules['Subject_Area'].unique().tolist()
    return render_template('view.html', subarealist=subarealist)

@app.route('/postfields')
def postfields():
    # this is were user selection from first function to pass and help select sheet from my excel
    dt = pd.read_excel('static/AllDataSheets.xlsx', sheetname='User selection from subarealist')
```

below is part of View.html code :

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_tables') }}" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
            <select name='fieldnames'onchange="this.form.submit()">
                {% for val in subarealist %}
                  <option value='{{val}}' selected="search_key" {% if search_key==val %}{% endif%}>{{val}}</option>
                  <option selected="selected"></option>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The form that you have in your HTML must be configured to post the form data to your second endpoint.

Comment: I have attached my html code, can you please suggest necessary changes @Miguel

Comment: Change the action attribute to point to your `postfields` route, then add handling of the form args in that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('postfields', sheet_name=val) }}" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
            <select name='fieldnames'onchange="this.form.submit()">
                {% for val in subarealist %}
                  <option value='{{val}}' selected="search_key" {% if search_key==val %}{% endif%}>{{val}}</option>
                  <option selected="selected"></option>
                {% endfor %}
```

And then change your function to:

```
@app.route('/postfields/<sheet_name>', methods=['POST'])
def postfields(sheet_name):
    # this is were user selection from first function to pass and help select sheet from my excel
    dt = pd.read_excel('static/AllDataSheets.xlsx', sheetname=sheet_name)
```

You may need to change the `sheet_name=val` section a bit, because I'm not sure exactly what kind of object `val` might be, or what properties it could have.  Just make sure that you're sending the data your function needs, and that your function is set to receive the type of data you're sending it.